# How do I unlock the alternate 'Ancestral' costumes for each class?

Tags: moon-hunters

Each class in Moon Hunters, in addition to the four palette swap color options, has an 'ancestral' costume, in which they glow with ghostly flames. This color scheme/costume is locked at the start of the game. How do I unlock it?

Answer (score 2):

To unlock the Ancestral costumes for the four base classes, you first need to find and visit the other Moon Hunters characters in their home town. After you find one of them, and speak to them, you'll find the other Hunter waiting for you at your campsite the next time you clear an area and rest.

Speak to them, and after a short conversation with some stat boosts, you'll unlock the Ancestral costume of that class for future playthroughs.

Comment: I'm unsure about the Sun Cultist... I unlocked it... somehow. Not sure what I did though!